# DEBChange (DCH), fixing the undocumented behaviour

Tags: debian, linux-mint, deb, dpkg

Use dpkg packet assembly on a project..

```
dch -v 1.2.3
```

The changelog file changed as expected:

```
package (1.2.3) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium                

  *                                                             
 -- Maintainer <email@example.com>  Fri, 08 Nov 2019 20:11:21 +0300
```

Then I use:

```
dch --release
```

The changelog reports the following:

```
package (1.2.3) bionic; urgency=medium 
...
```

instead of the expected:

```
package (1.2.3) unstable; urgency=medium 
...
```

as described in man dch.

Please advise..

P.S. using Mint OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an Ubuntu bug inherited by Mint. Ubuntu does weird crap like this and Bionic is an Ubuntu release name, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upstream Debian package `devscripts` behaves exactly as per the [documentation.](//manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/debchange.1.en.html) The problem is that you are using an Ubuntu-derived OS which has made some changes without updating the documentation.

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devscripts/+bug/1655717

Maybe you should raise a separate Mint bug because it doesn't look like Ubuntu is going to change this any time soon.  Or switch to a platform which is not based on Ubuntu if Mint is not central to your usage scenario.

The `dch` documentation shows how to work around this.

```sh
dch --release --distribution unstable
```

Comment: `dch --release --distribution unstable ` as alias `dchr` works exellent!